# How to handle Vue JS application when backend API application is not running?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling

When backend api application isn't working or not started, will receive following error in browser console.

```
OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user_token net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get(url, oprtions)
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // error.response, error.response.status, and so on
```

or

```
fetch(url, oprtions)
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // error.response, error.response.status, and so on
```

Read more about error handling:

- [Error/Exception handling in Vue.js application](https://medium.com/js-dojo/error-exception-handling-in-vue-js-application-6c26eeb6b3e4)
- [Dealing with Errors](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#Dealing-with-Errors)

Comment: Thanks for your response and I was able to handle it by catching error with below code if(!error.response){
     alert("Server not responding ");
    return;
}
But I need to place this in every API request and it is not a good practice and how should we handle this by placing this code at one place?